# tensorflow events file only written the first time by estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
# This script should train for one step and store the events file in model_dir:
model_dir = '/tmp/test'
shutil.rmtree(model_dir, ignore_errors=True)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn,
    params=params,
    model_dir=model_dir)

estimator.train(input_fn=make_input_fn(None), steps=1)
```

Now if I run `ls /tmp/test` I see this:

```
[quant@home tmp]$ ls test/
checkpoint  events.out.tfevents.1529978068.376da96eeba4  graph.pbtxt  model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001  model.ckpt-1.index  model.ckpt-1.meta
```

However, if I run the same script again with the same kernel (ie. in the same instance of my jupyter notebook), I see this:

```
[quant@home tmp]$ ls test/
checkpoint  graph.pbtxt  model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001  model.ckpt-1.index  model.ckpt-1.meta
```

If I change the name of my directory (e.g. to `/tmp/test2`) the events file is printed again, but only the first time.

Clearly there is some state being captured somewhere, but where, and how do I reset my estimator completely?

Comment: but you have steps=1, doesn't save according the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed some similar behaviors of this in Jupyter Notebook. I am using Python class to wrap all of these up, but this still cannot keep it 'clean'.

As I observe, after the event file was created, as long as I do not delete it, this file still keeps being updated. After I delete it, no new event file is created.

Up to now, I have three solutions:
1. restart Jupyter session, which is a bit of inconvenient.
2. keep using different directories.
3. keep the event file (which depends on your situation)